# MS SQL Server 2012; I have the following syntax error: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a syntax error with my SQL Server 2012 stored procedure:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'

Here is the code for my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_UpdateOnHandQtyByMrchRcvd 
     (@pn_location_id SMALLINT, 
      @pn_item_id NUMERIC)  
    BEGIN TRAN compute_inv_loc_bal; --Syntax Error near the KEYWORD 'BEGIN'
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @p_location_id  NUMERIC,
            @p_item_id NUMERIC,
            @p_qty NUMERIC,
            @p_on_hand_qty NUMERIC,
            @count INT,
            @p_trans_id NUMERIC,
            @p_trans_type_id INT,
            @p_trans_category_id INT,
            @p_trans_ref_id NUMERIC,
            @p_trans_type_code VARCHAR(35)

    -- reset item location qty
    UPDATE posit_db.dbo.item_location
    SET qty_on_hand = 0,
        updated_by = user_name(), 
        updated_date = getdate()
    WHERE location_id = @pn_location_id;

    -- Merchandise Received
    -- trans_type = MerRcvd, 10, trans_category = Purchase, 3
    DECLARE get_trans_data CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 
            it.location_id, it.trans_id, it.item_id, it.trans_type_id, 
            it.trans_category_id, it.trans_ref_id, it.qty,
            itt.trans_type_code
        FROM    
            posit_db..inventory_trans it, posit_db..inventory_trans_type itt
        WHERE 
            it.trans_type_id = itt.trans_type_id AND
            it.trans_category_id = itt.trans_category_id AND
            it.location_id = @pn_location_id AND
            it.trans_ref_id in (SELECT trans_id FROM posit_db..mrch_dist) AND
            it.item_id in (SELECT item_id FROM posit_db..mrch_dist) ;

    OPEN get_trans_data

    FETCH get_trans_data INTO @p_location_id, @p_trans_id, @p_item_id, @p_trans_type_id,
                              @p_trans_category_id, @p_trans_ref_id, @p_qty, @p_trans_type_code

    WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Shouldn't `BEGIN TRAN` be inside your `BEGIN`???

Answer (score 0):

It should be other way round. You first begin the procedure block and then begin the transaction block within it and no vice-versa like

```
create procedure dbo.sp_UpdateOnHandQtyByMrchRcvd (
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN compute_inv_loc_bal;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I've modified my original answer.

The error you get when trying to build your stored procedure is specifically due to the parameter declaration.  There should be no open/close parentheses around them.  Though not required, you may want to consider wrapping the code of your stored procedure in a `BEGIN`/`END` block, though as Dan Guzman points out with his comments, it's syntactically optional.  Also, I'd move the `BEGIN TRAN` statement after your variable declaration, though again, it's not required.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_UpdateOnHandQtyByMrchRcvd
    @pn_location_id  smallint, 
    @pn_item_id      numeric
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @p_location_id        numeric,
            @p_item_id            numeric,
            @p_qty                numeric, 
            @p_on_hand_qty        numeric,
            @count                int,
            @p_trans_id           numeric,
            @p_trans_type_id      int,
            @p_trans_category_id  int,
            @p_trans_ref_id       numeric,
            @p_trans_type_code    varchar(35)

    BEGIN TRAN compute_inv_loc_bal;

    /* REMAINDER OF YOUR STORED PROCEDURE GOES HERE... */

END
```

Comment: The BEGIN/END block is not required. The square brackets in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) indicate they are optional.

Comment: Though BEGIN/END is optional, I'd say it is highly recommended from my own experience for clearness and better formatting.